# What constitutes a read or write to memory/cache in x86 assembly, according to valgrind?

Tags: assembly, x86, valgrind, pascal, cpu-cache

I am looking into why some compiled Pascal code is slower than other languages/compilers for a simple test case. I believe it has to do with the preference of the FreePascal x86 compiler to use memory (and the CPU using the data cache) even on the highest optimization level, whereas other optimizing compilers will cheat and keep everything in registers if using memory is not explicitly required. When I run the program through valgrind's cachegrind tool I see a large amount of data references, and I am not entirely sure exactly which assembly instructions correspond to each read and write on the data cache. (The number of instruction references and branches reported by valgrind all make sense to me, but not the number of data references).

As a point of reference, here is the simple Pascal code. I am just calculating an xorshift random number 1 billion times.

```
program xorshifts;

var x:Uint64;
var i:longint;

function xorshifts(x:Uint64):Uint64;
begin
    x:=x xor (x>>12);
    x:=x xor (x<<25);
    x:=x xor (x>>27);
    xorshifts:=x*$2545F4914F6CDD1D;
end;

begin
    x:=1337;
    for i:=0 to 999999999 do
        x:=xorshifts(x);
    writeln(x);
end.
```

Here are the relevant parts of the compiled assembly code:

```
.Lj5:
addl    $1,U_$P$XORSHIFTS_$$_I(%rip)                ; increment i
movq    U_$P$XORSHIFTS_$$_X(%rip),%rdi              ; put the previous result in %rdi
call    P$XORSHIFTS_$$_XORSHIFTS$QWORD$$QWORD@PLT   ; call xorshift to get new result
movq    %rax,U_$P$XORSHIFTS_$$_X(%rip)              ; save the result
cmpl    $999999999,U_$P$XORSHIFTS_$$_I(%rip)        ; loop to i=1 billion
jnge    .Lj5

P$XORSHIFTS_$$_XORSHIFTS$QWORD$$QWORD: ; this is just the xorshift function, nothing to see here
movq    %rdi,%rax
shrq    $12,%rax
xorq    %rdi,%rax
movq    %rax,%rdx
shlq    $25,%rdx
xorq    %rax,%rdx
movq    %rdx,%rax
shrq    $27,%rax
xorq    %rdx,%rax
movq    $2685821657736338717,%rdx
imulq   %rdx,%rax
ret
```

Here is the cachegrind output: `valgrind --tool=cachegrind --branch-sim=yes ./xorshifts`

```
==27411== I   refs:      18,000,005,765
==27411== I1  misses:               151
==27411== LLi misses:               151
==27411== I1  miss rate:           0.00%
==27411== LLi miss rate:           0.00%
==27411== 
==27411== D   refs:       6,000,003,164  (4,000,001,091 rd   + 2,000,002,073 wr)
==27411== D1  misses:               134  (           20 rd   +           114 wr)
==27411== LLd misses:               134  (           20 rd   +           114 wr)
==27411== D1  miss rate:            0.0% (          0.0%     +           0.0%  )
==27411== LLd miss rate:            0.0% (          0.0%     +           0.0%  )
==27411== 
==27411== LL refs:                  285  (          171 rd   +           114 wr)
==27411== LL misses:                285  (          171 rd   +           114 wr)
==27411== LL miss rate:             0.0% (          0.0%     +           0.0%  )
==27411== 
==27411== Branches:       1,000,000,987  (1,000,000,974 cond +            13 ind)
==27411== Mispredicts:              277  (          270 cond +             7 ind)
==27411== Mispred rate:             0.0% (          0.0%     +          53.8%   )
```

So 18 billion instruction references - that makes sense because there are 18 instructions in the loop, and the loop executes 1 billion times.

1 billion branches. Fine.

But 6 billion data references, with 4 billion read and 2 billion write? I don't count 4 billion reads. Here's what I count:

```
.Lj5:
addl    $1,U_$P$XORSHIFTS_$$_I(%rip)                ; data write?
movq    U_$P$XORSHIFTS_$$_X(%rip),%rdi              ; data read?
call    P$XORSHIFTS_$$_XORSHIFTS$QWORD$$QWORD@PLT   ; 
movq    %rax,U_$P$XORSHIFTS_$$_X(%rip)              ; data write?
cmpl    $999999999,U_$P$XORSHIFTS_$$_I(%rip)        ; data read?
jnge    .Lj5
```

And FYI even the actual disassembled binary looks no different:

```
   4010d8:   ff ff ff
   4010db:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   4010e0:   83 05 59 d7 02 00 01    addl   $0x1,0x2d759(%rip)        # data write?
   4010e7:   48 8b 3d 42 d7 02 00    mov    0x2d742(%rip),%rdi        # data read?
   4010ee:   e8 9d ff ff ff          call   401090 
   4010f3:   48 89 05 36 d7 02 00    mov    %rax,0x2d736(%rip)        # data write?
   4010fa:   81 3d 3c d7 02 00 ff    cmpl   $0x3b9ac9ff,0x2d73c(%rip)        # data read?
   401101:   c9 9a 3b
   401104:   7c da                   jl     4010e0 <main+0x20>
```

Or 2 billion of each data read and data write, 4 billion total. Where do the other 2 billion read instructions come from? Does every write also count as a read? Does the call instruction count as a read/write/both? Is it related to the symbolic addressing? Does it have something to do with the PLT? Is valgrind smoking something?

And even worse, when you use callgrind instead of cachegrind, you get a different breakdown of the 6 billion data references: `valgrind --tool=callgrind --simulate-cache=yes ./xorshifts`

```
==13672== I1  misses:               151
==13672== LLi misses:               151
==13672== I1  miss rate:           0.00%
==13672== LLi miss rate:           0.00%
==13672== 
==13672== D   refs:       6,000,003,163  (3,000,001,083 rd + 3,000,002,080 wr)
==13672== D1  misses:               134  (           20 rd +           114 wr)
==13672== LLd misses:               134  (           20 rd +           114 wr)
==13672== D1  miss rate:            0.0% (          0.0%   +           0.0%  )
==13672== LLd miss rate:            0.0% (          0.0%   +           0.0%  )
==13672== 
==13672== LL refs:                  285  (          171 rd +           114 wr)
==13672== LL misses:                285  (          171 rd +           114 wr)
==13672== LL miss rate:             0.0% (          0.0%   +           0.0%  )
```

What is going on here? And more generally, because obviously I fail to understand, what constitutes a read or write?

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but I don't see how you would be able to `add` to a memory location without a read of that location. Also, the `call` should put the return address on the stack, which seems like another write and read to me.

Comment: @user17732522: The `push` operation done by a `call` is write-only to stack memory.  The RSP register is read+written to increment it.  Re: add, yes, it's an RMW.

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant the `ret` for the read.

Comment: @user17732522 You gave me the idea to modify the assembly to just increment thru i (just addl and cmpl). Cachegrind then gives 2 billion reads, 0 writes, while callgrind gives 1 billion of each. I don't see how cachegrind can be correct [addl IMM,(memory) must certainly be a write instruction]. In that case, your comment that call/ret must be counted a read/write to stack memory is definitely what I was missing. Still curious as to why cachegrind counts the data references incorrectly. Maybe what Peter said that "add" being RMW means cachegrind thinks it's R while callgrind thinks it's W.

Comment: The FPC _does_ have `{$optimization regVar}` enabled in [`‑O2`](https://freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse49.html) or higher. At least for version 3.2.0 this statement is true. If posting assembly output, use [`‑al`](https://freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap1.html), which will insert Pascal source code lines as comments to the generated `*.s` file, but also generate comments explaining _which_ register holds _which_ variable, so it’s far more “readable”. (Note, `‑a` will switch from the internal to the external assembler, so there’s _technically_ a _little_ difference.)

Comment: What happens if you use local variables instead of global ones for `x` and `i`? (i.e. put the body of the main program in a procedure).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Good point, if you move everything into a procedure and use at least -O2, that seems to force the use of registers for x and i instead of memory, reducing the number of data references to effectively zero. That brings the performance to essentially match that of C & Rust. Good to know that Pascal is much more performant when you iterate on local variables. That answers my underlying question, but I'm still curious as to why cachegrind and callgrind disagree on what constitutes read or write instructions.

Comment: If you account for memory destination `add` being R+W, do the numbers add up?  In real CPUs, memory-destination ALU instructions decode to load, ALU, and store uops, so HW perf counters would count that way.  (With or without `call` being a write, `ret` being a read?  Very plausible for different tools to count that or not). Your comments on the other instructions look obviously correct to me, including the read for `cmp` with a memory operand even if it's the second ("destination") position.

Answer (score 3):

1. 1. Compile with Valgrind debugging information:

      ```sh
      fpc -gv xorshifts.pas
      ```
   2. Collect some data:

      ```sh
      valgrind --tool=cachegrind --branch-sim=yes ./xorshifts & \
        sleep 2 && kill $!
      ```
   3. Examine [line-by-line counts](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cg-manual.line-by-line):

      ```sh
      cg_annotate --auto=yes cachegrind.out.$!
      ```
2. Assembly-level annotation:

   1. Use [`‑‑dump‑instr=yes`](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#opt.dump-instr):

      ```sh
      valgrind --tool=callgrind --simulate-cache=yes --dump-instr=yes ./xorshifts & \
        sleep 2 && kill $!
      ```
   2. As of Valgrind version 3.18, this information can only be viewed with KCachegrind.
      This is really confusing because the [text-style formatting in the documentation](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cg-manual.annopts.things-to-watch-out-for) suggests `callgrind_annotate(1)` could do just that.

      ```sh
      kcachegrind callgrind.out.$!
      ```
   3. Navigate to the “Machine Code” tab at the bottom bar.
3. 1. You are profiling the entire executable.
      The “missing” counts can possibly be attributed to the code executed before and after `PASCALMAIN`. Use `‑‑toggle‑collect=main` to count just this function.
   2. There is no instruction that can accept two memory operands as both the source *and* destination.
      Hence no instruction can be counted as *both* DR and DW.
   3. `call` is “essentially” shorthand for `push rip, jmp func`. The `push` is obviously a data write.
      Accordingly, `ret` is a data read access.
   4. It is not related to symbolic addressing.
   5. It has nothing to do with any PLT.
      If you compile your program without `‑gv` and run `ldd xorshift`, you will notice that it does not depend on any dynamic shared objects.
   6. Last time I checked, `valgrind(1)` ain’t smoking nothin’.